# Is there a word for place and year of birth and death?

Tags: single-word-requests

Imagine a form like this one:

- year of birth:
- place of birth:
- year of death:
- place of death:

How would you name that form?

Comment: I don't think there is a single word that encompasses this concept. If form design is your object, you might try looking at historical examples of birth and death records to find out what information is recorded. For example, [the death certificate for well-known writer Laura Ingalls Wilder](http://www.sos.mo.gov/archives/resources/deathcertificates/) uses the same words you've given, with the exception of *birthplace* instead of *place of birth*.

Comment: Maybe a tombstone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd label the form "[Vital Statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vital_statistics_%28government_records%29)" or "Birth and Death Data" or possibly "Personal Data", depending on the purpose of the form.  If you insist on using a single word for the form title, and don't like the aforementioned "Tombstone", you could miscall it a "Scorecard", "Annals", "Register", "Lifespan", "Vitals", etc.

Answer (score -3):

I believe it is an epitaph, the words that are written on a tombstone.

Comment: The definition of Epitaph is "An inscription on a gravestone in memory of the deceased." This answer is just wrong.